# Почему не отображается информация (аватар, записи, число записей) на странице автора wordpress

Tags: wordpress

питаюсь сделать страницу автора на вордпресс, но не получается вывести аватар пользователя когда гости просматривают страницу автора! Когда ты залогинен - тогда все ок аватар отображается и только твой, тоесть если зайти на страницу другого автора то будет всеравно отображатся только твой аватар

точно такая же беда с числом записей автора, и выводом записей того или инного автора.

использулью плагин для личного кабинета userswp
и код который не работает к примеру: `echo get_the_author() . ' опубликовал ' . get_the_author_posts() . ' статей.';`

`echo get_avatar(get_current_user_id(), 100);`

````
    get_current_user_id(), 
    array( 
        "size"   => "75", 
        "rating" => "X", 
        "scheme" => "http",
    ) 
); ?>" width=121>```

Может какой то цикл забыл указать или что, уже не знаю точно также не выводит дату регистрации автора!
хотя имя фамилию выводит
````